# Error when writing Spark Structured Streaming example in Clojure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, clojure, spark-structured-streaming, flambo

I am trying to rewrite Spark Structured Streaming example in Clojure.

The example is written in Scala as follows:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

```scala
(ns flambo-example.streaming-example
  (:import [org.apache.spark.sql Encoders SparkSession Dataset Row]
           [org.apache.spark.sql.functions]
           ))

(def spark
  (->
   (SparkSession/builder)
   (.appName "sample")
   (.master "local[*]")
   .getOrCreate)  
  )


(def lines
  (-> spark
      .readStream
      (.format "socket")
      (.option "host" "localhost")
      (.option "port" 9999)
      .load      
      )
  )

(def words
  (-> lines
      (.as (Encoders/STRING))      
      (.flatMap #(clojure.string/split  % #" " ))      
      ))
```

The above code causes the following exception.

;; Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
;; No matching method found: flatMap for class
;; org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

How can I avoid the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the signatures. Java `Dataset` API provides two implementations of `Dataset.flatMap`, one which takes `scala.Function1`

```
def flatMap[U](func: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

and the second one which takes Spark's own `o.a.s.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction`

```
def flatMap[U](f: FlatMapFunction[T, U], encoder: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

The former one is rather useless for you, but you should be able to use the latter one. For `RDD` API `flambo` [uses macros to create Spark friendly adapters](https://github.com/yieldbot/flambo/blob/develop/src/clojure/flambo/function.clj) which can be accessed with `flambo.api/fn` - I am not sure if these will work directly with `Datasets`, but you should be able to adjust them if you need.

Since you cannot depend on implicit `Encoders` you also have to provide explicit encoder which matches return type.

Overall you'll need something around:

```
(def words
  (-> lines
    (.as (Encoders/STRING))      
    (.flatMap f e)      
  ))
```

where `f` implements `FlatMapFunction` and `e` is an `Encoder`. One example implementation:

```
(def words
  (-> lines
      (.as (Encoders/STRING))      
      (.flatMap
        (proxy [FlatMapFunction] [] 
          (call [s] (.iterator (clojure.string/split s #" ")))) 
        (Encoders/STRING))))
```

but I guess it is possible to find a better one.

In practice I'd avoid typed `Dataset` whatsoever and focus on `DataFrame` (`Dataset[Row]`).